# Regulating FPS of game in Java

Tags: java, android, timing

I am trying to regulate the fps of a game I am creating in Java. It outputs every half-second the frame rate when it should do it every second. What mistakes am I making here. It is in Android so instead of `Thread.sleep(time)` `I use handler.postDelayed(this, time)`.

```
if(!m.isPaused){
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        frames ++;
        cd.tick();
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        counter += ((waitMs - 2) * 1000000) - (end - start);
        if(counter >= 1000000000){
            System.out.println("Frames: " + frames + " counter: " + counter);
            counter = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
        m.gameThread.postDelayed(this, waitMs - 2 - ((end - start) * 1000000));
        return;
    }
    m.gameThread.postDelayed(this, waitMs);
```

Comment: is it possible to see the full code of this class..?

Comment: This is pretty much the whole class since it is just a `Runnable`

Comment: I see.. I'm not pretty sure how you invoke it in the beginning.. and I also don't know how you control the `isPaused` value.. (and maybe the value of waitMs is 1000..? will the value of `waitMs - 2 - ((end - start) * 1000000)` will ever be minus..?)

but when it is paused, you will invoke this runnable class again in `waitMs` millisecond.. perhaps at that time, 2 runnables are overlapped and made an impression of being executed after half-second delay..